Model reduction in linear regression by stepwise elimination of predictors with "non-significant" coefficients
Before we start: yes, I am aware that stepwise model reduction suffers from many drawbacks and it is advisable to use regularisation methods such as LASSO instead. However, I found a procedure that seems to perform quite well in some preliminary tests and I would like to ask for the learned opinion of this community on it. So please hear me out :-)
The procedure in question is described in "The R Book" by Michael J. Crawley (2nd edition published by Wiley, see also the book's website), on Pages 493ff.
Crawley first fits a full model (after standardising the predictors) and then considers the set of predictors with "non-significant" coefficients (according to the usual t-test on whether a coefficient is "significantly" different from zero). The predictor with the coefficient that has the smallest absolute value in this set is then selected for removal, the fit is updated with R's update function and the procedure continues until there are no "non-significant" coefficients left.
I implemented this procedure in an R function that takes the result of a "maximal model fit" (e.g. full.model <- lm(resp ~ ., data=df):
drop.pred <- function(full.model, p.thr=0.05, verbose=T) {
  mod <- full.model
  summ <- summary(mod)
  if (verbose) {
    cat("Starting (full) model:\n")
    print(summ)
  }
  dropped <- character(0)
  repeat {
    coeff <- summ$coefficients[, "Estimate"][-1] # named vector of coefficients except Intercept
    pvals <- summ$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"][-1] # named vector of p-values except Intercept
    # index vector of "non-significant" coefficients
    nonsign.idx <- which(pvals > p.thr)
    if (length(nonsign.idx) == 0) {
      # all coefficients are "significant", we are done
      break
    }
    # Get the name of the non-significant coefficient closest to 0
    nonsign.coef <- coeff[nonsign.idx]
    smallest.coef.name <- names(which.min(abs(nonsign.coef)))
    dropped <- c(dropped, smallest.coef.name) # note what's dropped
    mod <- update(mod, as.formula(paste0("~.-", smallest.coef.name)))
    summ <- summary(mod)
    if (verbose) {
      cat("Dropped", smallest.coef.name, ", new model:\n")
      print(summ)
    }
  }
  return(list(final.model=mod, dropped.preds=dropped))
}

And tried it out on a simulated data set which consists of 7 predictors (pred1 ... pred7) and one response resp. The "true" relationship is resp <- 1.0 + 3*pred1 - 4*pred2 + 2*pred3 -0.5*pred5 + 1.5*pred7, the predictors pred4 and pred6 have "true" coefficients of 0 so they should be eliminated.
Of course, Gaussian errors with mean=0 and S.D.=0.2 were added to the response. For some additional fun, pred1,pred2,pred3 are strongly correlated (generated from linear transformations of a single Uniform random variate plus some Gaussian noise to make them a bit uncorrelated).
Here is an example run:
Starting (full) model:

Call:
lm(formula = resp ~ ., data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.04072 -0.33419  0.03873  0.32466  1.04460 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.08103    0.04857  22.257  < 2e-16 ***
pred1        2.31114    0.22040  10.486  < 2e-16 ***
pred2       -2.92169    0.23290 -12.545  < 2e-16 ***
pred3        1.27940    0.23008   5.561 2.61e-07 ***
pred4       -0.04544    0.05088  -0.893    0.374    
pred5       -0.32645    0.05175  -6.309 9.71e-09 ***
pred6        0.03542    0.05153   0.687    0.494    
pred7        0.74684    0.05024  14.865  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4857 on 92 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8645,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8542 
F-statistic: 83.88 on 7 and 92 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Dropped pred6 , new model:

Call:
lm(formula = resp ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3 + pred4 + pred5 + pred7, 
    data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.07436 -0.32710  0.02938  0.33354  1.00713 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.08960    0.04891  22.277  < 2e-16 ***
pred1        3.87267    0.35688  10.852  < 2e-16 ***
pred2       -4.86070    0.38505 -12.623  < 2e-16 ***
pred3        2.09298    0.37822   5.534 2.87e-07 ***
pred4       -0.08399    0.08656  -0.970    0.334    
pred5       -0.58954    0.09358  -6.300 9.79e-09 ***
pred7        1.52188    0.10152  14.992  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4843 on 93 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8638,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8551 
F-statistic: 98.34 on 6 and 93 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Dropped pred4 , new model:

Call:
lm(formula = resp ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3 + pred5 + pred7, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.08378 -0.28716  0.01194  0.34655  1.06993 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.08995    0.04889  22.292  < 2e-16 ***
pred1        3.86201    0.35660  10.830  < 2e-16 ***
pred2       -4.83000    0.38363 -12.590  < 2e-16 ***
pred3        2.09394    0.37810   5.538 2.77e-07 ***
pred5       -0.59176    0.09352  -6.328 8.39e-09 ***
pred7        1.52390    0.10146  15.019  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4842 on 94 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8625,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8551 
F-statistic: 117.9 on 5 and 94 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

[1] "pred6" "pred4"

Call:
lm(formula = resp ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3 + pred5 + pred7, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.08378 -0.28716  0.01194  0.34655  1.06993 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.08995    0.04889  22.292  < 2e-16 ***
pred1        3.86201    0.35660  10.830  < 2e-16 ***
pred2       -4.83000    0.38363 -12.590  < 2e-16 ***
pred3        2.09394    0.37810   5.538 2.77e-07 ***
pred5       -0.59176    0.09352  -6.328 8.39e-09 ***
pred7        1.52390    0.10146  15.019  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4842 on 94 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8625,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8551 
F-statistic: 117.9 on 5 and 94 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

The usual model comparison with anova() gives the expected result:
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: resp ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3 + pred4 + pred5 + pred6 + pred7
Model 2: resp ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3 + pred5 + pred7
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     92 21.703                           
2     94 22.035 -2   -0.3323 0.7043 0.4971

Running the script repeatedly with new random datasets gives the same result,
the only difference is that sometimes pred4 and sometimes pred6 get eliminated first.
Obviously for a "real" analysis one would need a cross-validation-like approach, e.g. generating 10 random subsets of the original data, run the procedure on them and then settle for the final model that was produced most of the time, and/or that gave the "best result" on the test sets according to the usual criteria (RMSE, R2 etc.)
Because this procedure seems to be quite intuitive, I would like to demonstrate it to my students as part of a practical course in linear regression (e.g. they would eliminate predictors "by hand" to get a feel for the technique). I would also like to compare it to e.g. LASSO, which is maybe less intuitive but most likely has a more solid theoretical foundation.
Finally, my questions:

Should I mention this procedure at all, or is it to be considered evil? :-)
If this procedure is worth teaching, then what would be the most appropriate way to make it robust (see my CV musings above)?

Thank you.

If you're aware of the problems with stepwise regression, I'm curious about why you think it does not apply to this, and what the goal is.

@mkt I wanted to get a second opinion from people who are more knowledgeable than I am. The goal is to figure out whether to teach this or not, or mention it with a stern warning like "you may see approaches like this in a textbook, but sometimes textbooks are wrong". See also Christian Hennig's detailed answer below.

IMO Crawley's book is like Strunk and White's Elements of Style; while the overall general principles are good, there is also some really awful and incorrect technical advice ...

This procedure looks like standard backward elimination based on p-values except for the "smallest absolute value" selection, which only makes sense if predictors are standardised. The major issue with it is that the computation of p-values assumes that no data dependent selection has been done before, and this means that all p-values after the first step are invalid. In particular it means that the final significant p-values for all remaining variables cannot be trusted, and that the procedure systematically selects variables the parameters of which have  high absolute values. A consequence of this is that at the end of the selection the absolute values of these parameters will be biased high (which is why Lasso does shrinking).
I have seen (but don't remember anymore where) simulations in which backward elimination was compared with Lasso when it comes to prediction error, and I have occasionally compared the two using cross-validation on the same data with results in line with results roughly explained below. What I have written above does not directly refer to the prediction error, and one could wonder whether the prediction error is the first thing to worry about (if people are careful enough to not overinterpret the final p-values and parameter estimates). In fact there are some situations in which this procedure will beat Lasso when it comes to the prediction error, although in other situations Lasso is better. I can't really make a quantitative statement about which one "wins more often", and this will crucially depend on how exactly a simulation study is set up, but it'd be wrong to think that Lasso is always better.
The problem with teaching this is that, even though not uniformly worse than Lasso, it tempts people into interpreting the final p-values, which are invalid. Also although the procedure itself is simple, it is not so simple to teach it together with appropriate warnings and then try to explain why it is still occasionally good despite being invalid. Students may very well not appreciate this; in my experience some have issues when a lecturer teaches something, even maybe recommends to use it, and then makes some effort to also explain what's wrong with it. On the other hand one may think that students should know all this.
Note also that I have seen students coming up with this idea themselves or at least doing such things without explicitly being taught to do that - either because the idea is so intuitive that students can come up with it themselves after having been exposed to some overinterpretation of the "significance" concept so that they think an insignificant variable should be kicked out, or because they picked it up somewhere on the web. In which case it could make sense to mention it and say what's wrong with it.
For any given real data set, if prediction quality is important in the first place and there is enough data to do reliable cross validation, one could use CV to compare Lasso and backward elimination and use what comes out best of course, but I'm not sure whether there is enough time to introduce students into all the aspects of this issue required to properly appreciate and understand this.
Note also that alternatively there's backward elimination based on AIC or other criteria, and I expect this to do better when it comes to prediction quality than backward elimination based on p-values more often than not; the AIC is better adapted to prediction than the p-values, although I haven't explored this systematically. The AIC will not be biased by preliminary selection, but final resulting p-values will still be biased even if selected by AIC and not by p-values themselves.

I think the third paragraph nails it. Stepwise regression can be competitive when it comes to pure prediction, provided valid methods are used to evaluate the predictions (no calculating adjusted $R^2$ based on the number of surviving variables, for instance). However, it is so easy to misinterpret this that the message must be crystal clear. That software packages may be perfectly happy to report adjusted $R^2$ based on the number of "surviving" variables does not help matters.
